# Are som rasa and Madhu different kind of juices (alcohol?) or are they the same thing?

Tags: puranas, soma

I've been reading puranas, and at many places the demi gods take part in *somapanam* which might be some kind of juice or wine, but the word for hard alcohol in Sanskrit is madhu. So my question is whether madhu and soma are the same thing or not.Is there mention of the making procedure of these liquids in puranas? I'm guessing that soma is not alcohol and is some kind of Divine juice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kshatriyas and alcohol consumption](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18770/3500)

Answer (score 4):

Yes anubhav jha soma is not alcohol but divine substance the full [book 9](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandala_9) is soma devoted.

Check it out:—

> We have drunk Soma and
>   become immortal; we have
>   attained the light, the Gods
>   discovered. Now what may
>   foeman's malice do to harm
>   us? What, O Immortal, mortal
>   man's deception?
>
> —**[Rig Veda: Rig-Veda, Book 8:
>   HYMN XLVIII. Soma](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv08048.htm)**

And madhu it is simply honey.

Brihadaranyaka
Upanishad, contains a
chapter called the Madhu
Brahmana and "the secret
essence of the Vedas themselves,
was called the madhu-vidya or
honey doctrine."
The fifth brahmana of the second
chapter introduces the Madhu
theory , thus giving this section of
the Upanishad the ancient name
Madhu Khanda .

There is nothing alcoholic

**FIFTH BRAHMANA**

> I. This earth is the
>   honey (madhu, the
>   effect) of all beings, and
>   all beings are the honey
>   (madhu, the effect) of
>   this earth. Likewise this
>   bright, immortal person
>   in this earth, and that
>   bright immortal person
>   incorporated in the body
>   **(both are madhu)**. He
>   indeed is the same as
>   that Self, that Immortal,
>   that Brahman, that All.
>
> 2. This water is the
>      honey of all beings, and
>      all beings are the honey
>      of this water. Likewise
>      this bright, immortal
>      person in this water,
>      and that bright,
>      immortal person,
>      existing as seed in the
>      body **(both are madhu)**.
>      He indeed is the same
>      as that Self, that
>      Immortal, that Brahman,
>      that All.
>
> —**[brihadaranyaka upnishad:adhyaya II:fifth brahmana](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/upanishads/brihad.asp)**

Answer (score 2):

**Soma and Madhu are completely different.** This can be discerned from the different rules prescribed for the drinking of Soma and Madhu in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu11.htm) of the Manu Smriti:

> 7. He who may possess (a supply of) food sufficient to maintain those dependant on him during three years or more than that, is worthy to drink the Soma-juice.
> 8. But a twice-born man, who, though possessing less than that amount of property, nevertheless drinks the Soma-juice, does not derive any benefit from that (act), though he may have formerly drunk the Soma-juice....
> 9. Sura one must know to be of three kinds, that distilled from molasses (gaudi), that distilled from ground rice, and that distilled from Madhuka-flowers (madhvi); as the one (named above) even so are all (three sorts) forbidden to the chief of the twice-born.
> 10. Sura, (all other) intoxicating drinks and decoctions and flesh are the food of the Yakshas, Rakshasas, and Pisakas; a Brahmana who eats (the remnants of) the offerings consecrated to the gods, must not partake of such (substances).