# Does Manusmriti (or similar works) prescribe punishments for Brahmins who propagate scripture to the undeserving?

Tags: manu-smriti, punishment

In particular, I want to know the penalty (if any) for teaching scripture to Mlecchas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following verse says that the sin a Brahmin commits by teaching someone who is undeserved is removed by Japa (reciting sacred texts) and Homa (burnt offerings).

> Manu Smriti 10.111. The guilt incurred by offering sacrifices for
>   teaching (unworthy men) is removed by muttering (sacred texts) and by
>   burnt offerings, but that incurred by accepting gifts (from them) by
>   throwing (the gifts) away and by austerities.

Another verse which is giving a punishment for revealing the secret of Vedas to strangers or to persons who are unworthy to know such secrets.

> 11.197. He who has sacrificed for Vratyas, or has performed the obsequies of strangers, or a magic sacrifice (intended to destroy
>   life) or an Ahina sacrifice, removes (his guilt) by three Krikkhra
>   (penances)
>
> 11.198. **A twice-born man** **who has** cast off a suppliant for protection, or has (improperly) **divulged the Veda, atones for his
>   offence, if he subsists during a year on barley**

Comment: I am going to accept of course - but I want to get it straight - of the two partners in a crime, one gets his tongue cut off and the other gets a wrist-slapping - is that right? @rickross

Comment: I know what u are talking abt ... If a Sudra hears the Vedas something terrible must happen to him .. but that's probably different from the case where one is intentionally teaching him (for money or something else).. @SK

Comment: @SK Yes generally, because it depends on the crime and the caste concerned. On the other hand, a Brahmana who drinks liquor should atone for it by killing himself by drinking boiling liquor, whereas a Shudra does not sin by drinking liquor.

Comment: This is false info.  A Brahmin has an easier out if he drinks.

Comment: @SK "A twice-born person, having, through folly, drunk wine, shall drink wine red-hot; he becomes freed from his guilt, when his body has been completely burnt by it."—Manusmriti (11.90); on the section titled "Expiation of drinking liquor (sura)"

Comment: @SK https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201969.html

Comment: @SK Gautama (23.1).—‘They shall pour hot wine into the mouth of a Brāhmaṇa who has drunk wine; he will be purified by death.’

Comment: @SK "Wine indeed is the dirty refuse of grains, and sin also is called ‘dirt’; for this reason the Brāhmaṇa, the Kṣatriya and the Vaiśya shall not drink wine."

Comment: Manusmriti 11.92.  Also Krishna and Arjuna drink in the Mahabharata.

Comment: @SK The Prayaschitta in 11.92 is for: "This verse is quoted in Mitākṣarā (3.254), which adds that this refers to a case where wine has been drunk by mistake and then vomitted;—again, as referring to a case where the, wine has been taken unitentionally but thrown out, after it has merely touched the palate."

Comment: @SK Krishna and Arjuna were kshatriyas, kshatriyas can drink a certain type of liquor.

Comment: @SK Krishna and Arjuna drank the kind of alcohol that's allowed for Kshatriyas; see here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18773/36